# ReactJS- can't read JSON array

Tags: json, reactjs

My App.jsx file is below.

```
import React from 'react';
class App extends React.Component {
constructor() {
  super();

  this.state = {
     data:require('json!./dataa.json')

  }
}

render() {
  return (
    <body>
     <div>
        <Header/>
        <center>
        <table>
        <tr><th>NAME</th><th>VALUE</th><th>COLOR</th><th>Edit Table</th></tr>
           <tbody>
           {this.state.data.table.map(person, i) => <TableRow key = {i} data = {person} />)}
           </tbody></table></center>
     </div>
     </body>
  );
}
}

 class Header extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return (
     <div><center>
        <h1>Creation of table from JSON</h1></center>
     </div>
  );
  }
  }

   class TableRow extends React.Component {
   render() {
   return (
     <tr>
        <td>{this.props.data.NAME}</td>
        <td>{this.props.data.VALUE}</td>
        <td>{this.props.data.COLOR}</td>
         <td contentEditable='true'></td>
        </tr>
        );
         }
         }
```

export default App;

and my dataa.json file is like below

```
[{"table":
[{"NAME":"Alan","VALUE":12,"COLOR":"blue"},
{"NAME":"Shan","VALUE":13,"COLOR":"green"},
{"NAME":"John","VALUE":45,"COLOR":"orange"},
{"NAME":"Minna","VALUE":27,"COLOR":"teal"}]
}]
```

Question: It is compiled fine. but it display error in browser "cannot read the property of map undefined".How to resolve

**Note: but it works fine when the json file like,**

```
[{"NAME":"Alan","VALUE":12,"COLOR":"blue"},
{"NAME":"Shan","VALUE":13,"COLOR":"green"},
{"NAME":"John","VALUE":45,"COLOR":"orange"},
{"NAME":"Minna","VALUE":27,"COLOR":"teal"}]
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.state.data` doesn't have property `table`, because it is an array of *single* object.

Correct JSON structure to this

```
{
  "table": [
    {"NAME":"Alan","VALUE":12,"COLOR":"blue"},
    {"NAME":"Shan","VALUE":13,"COLOR":"green"},
    {"NAME":"John","VALUE":45,"COLOR":"orange"},
    {"NAME":"Minna","VALUE":27,"COLOR":"teal"}
  ]
}
```

and use `this.state.data.table.map`.

Comment: this.state.data.table.map doesn't work fine. ERROR in ./app/components/dataa.jsonYou may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (2:9)